# Spring Security session null pointer error at onExpiredSessionDetected

Tags: spring-security

I have added Spring Security Session Registry to my web application to log and maintain session info.

I want to limit the possible sessions for a user to only 2. I believe that the way I have it configured once someone logs in a third time, the least recently used session expires (exceptionIfMaximumExceeded is false).

I'm using the following configuration in my *applicationContext.xml*:

```
<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter"> 
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" /> 
    <beans:constructor-arg name="expiredUrl" value="/login" /> 
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="compositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy"/>
            <beans:ref bean="concurrentSessionControlStrategy"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="concurrentSessionControlStrategy"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
    <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="false"/>
    <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="2"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

But a null pointer error is thrown at **o.s.s.w.s.ConcurrentSessionFilter** method **onExpiredSessionDetected** when someone logs in a third time. Is there something lacking in my configuration that would prevent this?

```
logback-test 2020-04-16 09:08:42,758 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] [39mDEBUG[0;39m o.s.s.w.s.ConcurrentSessionFilter - Requested session ID EBB664413F11D4510D7C780D982818BF has expired.
logback-test 2020-04-16 09:08:42,758 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] [39mDEBUG[0;39m o.s.s.w.a.l.SecurityContextLogoutHandler - Invalidating session: EBB664413F11D4510D7C780D982818BF
logback-test 2020-04-16 09:08:42,759 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] [39mDEBUG[0;39m o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionEventPublisher - Publishing event: org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionDestroyedEvent[source=org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@46615274]
logback-test 2020-04-16 09:08:42,759 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] [39mDEBUG[0;39m o.s.s.c.s.SessionRegistryImpl - Removing session EBB664413F11D4510D7C780D982818BF from principal's set of registered sessions
logback-test 2020-04-16 09:08:42,759 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] [39mDEBUG[0;39m o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
logback-test 2020-04-16 09:08:42,759 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] [39mDEBUG[0;39m o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
Apr 16, 2020 9:08:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [MyProfileServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter$1.onExpiredSessionDetected(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:145)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone runs into this issue, I found a solution in the **Concurrency Control** section of the Spring docs at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#concurrent-sessions.

Specifically, I needed to add a ***sessionInformationExpiredStrategy*** argument (instantiating SimpleRedirectSessionInformationExpiredStrategy) into my ***concurrentSessionFilter***, replacing the *expiredUrl* argument that I had there.

Not sure where the *expiredUrl* argument had come from, as it was in the legacy xml I was working with. Maybe it worked with a prior version of Spring Security.

```
<beans:bean id="redirectSessionInformationExpiredStrategy"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.session.SimpleRedirectSessionInformationExpiredStrategy">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="invalidSessionUrl" value="/login.jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter"> 
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" /> 
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionInformationExpiredStrategy" ref="redirectSessionInformationExpiredStrategy" />
</beans:bean>
```